# How to alter the $item value in taxonomy_field_is_empty without altering core taxonomy module?

Tags: 7, entities, hooks

How to alter the `$items` value found in `hook_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element)` and pass it to `hook_field_is_empty($item,$field)`?

In a custom module,

```
function hook_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element){
$item = $items[$delta];
}
```

In taxonomy.module,

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_is_empty().
 */
function taxonomy_field_is_empty($item, $field) {
  print_r($item);print_r($field);die('edd');
  if (!is_array($item) || empty($item['tid']) && (string) $item['tid'] !== '0') {
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

The  $item array structure in hook_field_is_empty($item,$field) is $item[0]['tid'] 
whereas taxonomy_field_is_empty($item,$field) expects to have structure as $item['tid'] .

[image]

Since its $item[0]['tid'], it gives undefined 'tid' which leads to returned value to be TRUE and hence field is said to be empty ,which is not the case usually.

I tried adding a custom hook in my module for hook_field_is_empty but it did not execute the hook at all ,even I tried adding -1 weight so it executes before taxonomy_field_is_empty (taxonomy module has weight 0) but still it did not help

So I need to alter $items value in hook_field_widget_form in a way that taxonomy_field_is_empty($item,$field) gets $item value such that $item['tid'] is defined(which was not case due to $item['0']['tid'] )

Is there any way I can alter $item value in hook_field_is_empty ?

Answer (score 1):

Altering `taxonomy_field_is_empty`'s behavior is, by definition, altering core, so the answer is no. Hacking core shouldn't be done (unless there's a clear **what** & **why** you're doing the hacking).

With that said, you should follow back on your original problem:

> I tried adding a custom hook in my module for hook_field_is_empty but it did not execute the hook at all ,even I tried adding -1 weight so it executes before taxonomy_field_is_empty (taxonomy module has weight 0) but still it did not help

The problem is, for some reason, your module's `hook_field_is_empty` implementation isn't firing so you'll need to troubleshoot that problem.

Look at other module [implementations](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/implementations/hook_field_is_empty/7.x) of the hook to see what those are doing that your module isn't and throw debug statements into [`module_invoke_all`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_invoke_all/7.x) to see if your module's hook is even recognized by core.